# Is there a way to show floating layout preview window in Android Studio 3.6 canary 9, 10

Tags: android, android-studio, preview, android-studio-3.6

After Android Studio update to canary 9, design for layout window has been changed, the preview window is no more separate, and I can't make it Float

What I want is to preview the layout in a separate window (like it was before canary 9)

Window -> Active Tool Window -> View Mode -> Float - disabled, can't choose it

Wiew -> Tool Windows - no Preview option

Answer (score 1):

Its Layout Validation
Wiew -> Tool Windows - Layout Validation
it works, it also shows you the preview of all devices

Comment: thanks, close enough, but its only for watching, no interaction with code